# ExtJS record.endEdit() performance very low

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a record which consists of approx 35-40 fields. When I try to set the value for 4-5 fields and try record.endEdit() it takes around 450 ms to be completed. Any idea on how I can reduce the processing time for it?

Comment: does your record belongs to a store?

Comment: yes, so I have to change 4-5 fields of record in my code. And after this, when I do record.endEdit, it takes around 450 ms to finish the process.

Comment: Do you call record.beginEdit()  before setting the fields?

Comment: Yes I added beginEdit at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time seems really strange you could override [`endEdit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-endEdit) with some timers to see what takes so long:

```js
endEdit : function(silent, modifiedFieldNames){
    console.time("endEdit");
    var me = this,
        dataSave,
        changed;

    silent = silent === true;
    if (me.editing) {
        me.editing = false;
        dataSave = me.dataSave;
        me.modifiedSave = me.dataSave = me.dirtySave = null;
        if (!silent) {
            if (!modifiedFieldNames) {
                console.time("getModifiedFieldNames");
                modifiedFieldNames = me.getModifiedFieldNames(dataSave);
                console.timeEnd("getModifiedFieldNames");
            }
            changed = me.dirty || modifiedFieldNames.length > 0;
            if (changed) {
                console.time("afterEdit");
                me.afterEdit(modifiedFieldNames);
                console.timeEnd("afterEdit");
            }
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd("endEdit");
}
```

this will print 3 times to the console so you can see what function takes so long